# In Snowflake SQL or Snowpark or Pandas, how do I filter records which have data for consecutive months?

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Given this sample table:

| id | sales | sales_date_monthend |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 2023-05-31 |
| 1 | 10 | 2023-04-30 |
| 1 | 11 | 2023-03-31 |
| 1 | 12 | 2023-02-27 |
| 1 | 1 | 2023-01-31 |
| 1 | 5 | 2022-12-31 |
| 1 | 3 | 2022-11-30 |
| 1 | 6 | 2022-10-31 |
| 1 | 9 | 2022-09-30 |
| 1 | 8 | 2022-08-31 |
| 1 | 7 | 2022-07-31 |
| 1 | 3 | 2023-06-30 |
| 1 | 2 | 2023-05-31 |
| 2 | 8 | 2022-08-31 |
| 2 | 7 | 2022-07-31 |
| 2 | 3 | 2023-06-30 |
| 2 | 2 | 2023-05-31 |

I want to return or filter the id which have sales data for the **last 12 consecutive months**, i.e., data in every month. For example id=1 has sales each month, but id=2 is missing some data.

I think there must be an easier way in Python, I tried to generate a date range as so:

```
SELECT last_day(dateadd(month,-seq8(0), DATE_TRUNC('month', CURRENT_DATE)))::date AS monthend
  FROM table (generator(rowcount => 100))
```

And I want to use this month-end dates to compare, if ids do have data on each consecutive months. I thought it would be something like this in Snowpark, but I cannot get it

```
# Left join the table with the generated date range
joined_table = date_range.join(sample_table, on='month', how='left')

# Define the window specification
window_spec = Window.orderBy('month').rowsBetween(-11, 0)

# Add a lag column to compare the revenue with the previous 12 months
joined_table_with_lag = joined_table.withColumn('sales', lag('revenue').over(window_spec))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using GROUP BY and HAVING:

```
SELECT id
FROM table
WHERE sales_date_monthend >= DATEADD(YEAR, -1, LAST_DAY(CURRENT_DATE()))
GROUP BY id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT TO_VARCHAR(sales_date_monthend, 'YYYY-MM') = 12;
```

If more columns are needed:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE sales_date_monthend >= DATEADD(YEAR, -1, LAST_DAY(CURRENT_DATE()))
QUALIFY COUNT(DISTINCT TO_VARCHAR(sales_date_monthend, 'YYYY-MM') 
        OVER(PARITITON BY id) = 12
```

Comment: This appears to work, but any idea how I can select all or more columns from the table, without having to group by all the selected columns?

Comment: I would like to select the sales_date_monthend, but when I include it, it does not return any records

Comment: @Dametime Yes, it is possible to return entire rows - one possibility is qualify and windowed count instead of aggreagation

Comment: This works, thanks. But why do you include the `distinct` in the count? The query appears to work without it.